# How can I find the Max/Min value in SQL Server as well as the time it occurred at?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time

I have a table that is being updated every 10 minutes with data of flow rates, at the end of the day I need a query that will generate the Average flow, the minimum flow value and the time it occurred at (same with max) and then the total flow for the day. I have this so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM [WS6].[dbo].[MasterData]
Where [_Datetime] between '2015-07-06' and '2015-07-06 23:59:59'
```

This gets me the whole days data, but how can I filter for the values I need? Thank you

Comment: You need to describe your table, the fields, data types, etc..

Comment: I'm using 2008 with the table giving me 144 entries (the flow that was updated every 10 minutes from the SCADA it's connected to), they're real type integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012, you can use `first_value()`:

```
SELECT avg(flow), min(flow), max(flow), sum(flow),
       first_value(_DateTime) over (order by flow asc) as minTime,
       first_value(_DateTime) over (order by flow desc) as maxTime
FROM [WS6].[dbo].[MasterData]
Where [_Datetime] >= '2015-07-06' and [_Datetime]  < '2015-07-07';
```

In earlier versions you can use window functions or `cross apply`.

Comment: `first_value()` is also available in SQL Server 2012

Comment: Without using `GROUP BY flow` this will give an error to include _flow_ in an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. See similar [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=381ab7cabaf074e993b458550271a7bb).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to get the Min and Max value on. for example if you are trying to get the min and max of field between those dates you would do something like this where _field is the filed you want the value for (will return 1 or no rows):

```
SELECT MIN(_field) AS 'MIN', MAX(_field) AS 'MAX'
FROM [WS6].[dbo].[MasterData]
Where [_Datetime] between '2015-07-06' and '2015-07-06 23:59:59'
```

if you are trying to get the min and max of many fields grouped by another field you can try something like this (may return many, 1 or no rows).

```
SELECT Group_by_field, MIN(_field) AS 'MIN', MAX(_field) AS 'MAX'
FROM [WS6].[dbo].[MasterData]
Where [_Datetime] between '2015-07-06' and '2015-07-06 23:59:59'
Group by Group_by_field
```

It would be helpful if you provided a sample table and sample output of what you want to do.

Comment: I wanted to attach a screenshot of my table to show you guys, but it says I need at least 10 reputation to attach images...

Comment: Just copy and paste it out of the MMC and throw in in a code block, does not have to be pretty, just good enough for us to figure out what your going for!